# Put multiple arrays in Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsarray

I am parsing a CSV file multiple times with for loop, here I need to store these arrays one by one dictionary. There are very less questions in stack about adding NSArray to NSDictionary. I am parsing CSV with below code but I strucked at storing in NSDictionary, The program is terminating and showing warning at assigning string to dictionary

```
for (i=0; i<=57; i++) {
    NSString *keysString = [csvArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *keysArray = [keysString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"Serail No %d %@",i,keysArray);
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: keysArray forKeys: string];
  }
```

Comment: what is an issue, error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for (i=0; i<=57; i++) {
 NSString *keysString = [csvArray objectAtIndex:i];
 NSArray *keysArray = [keysString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
 NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"serial%d",i];
 [dict setObject:keysArray forKey:key];

 }
```

To get back data from dictionary,

```
NSArray *array = [dict valueForKey:@"serial24"];//to get array 24.
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add the arrays to a dictionary, with the key being the string value of integer `i` ?  What you need to do is allocate the dictionary outside your loop -

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
for (i=0; i<=57; i++) {
   NSString *keysString = [csvArray objectAtIndex:i];
   NSArray *keysArray = [keysString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
   NSLog(@"Serial No %d %@",i,keysArray);
   NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
   dict[string]=keysArray;
}
```

I am not sure why you would want to do this, because this is basically an array.  You could simply do -

```
NSMutableArray *outputArray=[NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *keysString in csvArray) {
   NSArray *keysArray = [keysString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
   [outputArray addObject:keysArray];
}
```